# Error on line 35 in a 32 line program

Tags: java, excel, date

Here is what my code looks like:

```
public class ExcelManip {

    public static void main(String args[])
            throws ExcelException, FileNotFoundException {
        Application application = new Application();
        File xslFile = 
          new File("C:\\Users\\Nathan.Shnipes\\Documents\\Workbook.xlsx");
        Workbook workbook = application.openWorkbook(xslFile, true);
        Worksheet worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
        Range range = worksheet.getRange("A1:AD1");
        Variant[][] results = range.getValues();
        Cell cell = worksheet.getCell("A1");
        System.out.println(cell.getString());
        System.out.println(results[0][0].getValue());
        System.out.println(
            "C:\\Users\\Nathan.Shnipes\\Documents\\Workbook.xlsx");
        Range range2 = worksheet.getRange("o1:o500");
        Variant[][] dates = range2.getValues();
        System.out.println(dates[0][0].getValue());
    }
}
```

or as an image:

[image]

It's been throwing an error consistently on line 35. I deleted everything past line 35 as it worked up to that point, but it didn't help. I really have no idea whats wrong. I have tried copying the body of the program and placing it into a new class, but for whatever reason that has been throwing a no main error, even though it had the line `public static void main(String[] args) throws ***`

Comment: Maybe you first should fix the red "!" at the project

Comment: choose better names for class names

Comment: Can't read that code. Please paste it here along with the exception message.

Comment: @lupz open the picture in a new tab to enlarge it.

Comment: @lupz the code is readable. If you view the image, and then zoom in, you can read it. (But certainly you shouldn't have to do this, and OP ought to include the code.)

Comment: @Tom clicking it does not do anything here.

Comment: @chiastic-security the original image src is indeed readable, ty.

Comment: @getlost [cmd] + [+] over here ;)

Comment: @lupz you're right and I already edited that comment :).

Comment: sorry about that, i should have, i just wanted to make sure that i included the error prompts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a red exclamaition mark on your project. Eclipse is likly to not build your project if build path problems (e.g.) aren't resolved. So go to the `Problems` tab and try to resolve your errors there. If that is finished Eclipse will build your project and gives more helpful errors

**Edit**
and that is why you are running the old version (no new build replaced your old one), in which there is actually a line 35.

Comment: Perhaps you might want to add that while the project isn't rebuilt he will be running an old version of his class-file....

Comment: thank you for helping and not being a condescending about it. its much appriciated